# Problems, using p5.js width and height methods inside an object

Tags: p5.js

Hello I'm having trouble understanding where and where not I can use p5.js methods. In this [codepen](http://codepen.io/makingsnippets/pen/XRMwZa),

```
var bubble = {
  x: 200,
  y: 200,
  display: function() {
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(4);
    noFill();
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 24, 24);
  },
  move: function() {
    this.x = this.x + random(-1, 1);
    this.y = this.y + random(-1, 1);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);

}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  bubble.display();
  bubble.move();
  ellipse(width/2,height/2,50,50)
}
```

If I replace the x and y values inside my 'bubble' object with, for example, 'width/2' and 'height/2' - console prints 'width' is not defined? If I use the same method inside the draw() function it works fine. I'm guessing this is a scoping problem? But not sure how to get around it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var bubble = {
  init : function(){
   this.x = width/2;
   this.y = height/2;
  },
  display: function() {
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(4);
    noFill();
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 24, 24);
  },
  move: function() {
    this.x = mouseX;
    this.y = mouseY;
  }
}
```

I can't tell you why it doesn't work, i can't figure it out, but here is a working solution

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: this works because the context of the anonymous function is properly scoped within the display and setup methods to the p5 instance, whereas the plain object is scoped to the global window. The p5 authors makes this complicated by supporting global methods like this.